# Interpolate data from dictionary given a float index position

Tags: python, json, dictionary, floating-point, interpolation

I have a json file with data tuples of torque figures for given temperatures. Say I pull the data figures from the 46 degree portion:

```
j = {"46": [[88.0, 95.3], [86.1, 93.4], [84.2, 91.3], [82.8, 89.7], [80.8, 87.8]]}
```

If I am then given a floating point number as a reference index position, for example:

```
index = 1.85
```

Is it possible to interpolate from the data using just the float index location??
Obviously if I try a straight float as an index position it gives me:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

At the moment I am finding the nearest integers above and below the float and am then interpolating manually, but it is tedious. I am needing the interpolation for both of the numbers given in tuple.. for example, at index `1.85` I am doing:

```
lower_first_num = j["46"][1][0]
upper_first_num = j["46"][2][0]

difference = lower_first_num - upper_first_num
result = lower_first_num - (difference * .85)
```

Where .85 is the percent between the two index points. I would then have to do this again for the second number in the tuple.

In regard to the index floats given, they could be many various numbers as this program will run hundreds of times with different figures.

I'm just wondering if there is a pre-built method that I can use please...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to linearly interpolate between values, you could very likely just tweak your code very slightly, using the [`math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor) and [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil)  functions to grab the indices above and below the given index. The modulo (`%`) operator allows us to grab the decimal place.

Something like this should suffice:

```
from math import floor, ceil

data = j["46"] # [[88.0, 95.3], [86.1, 93.4], [84.2, 91.3], [82.8, 89.7], [80.8, 87.8]]

index = 1.85

before, after = data[floor(index)][0], data[ceil(index)][0] # 86.1, 84.2
step = index % 1 # .85
difference = after - before # -1.9
lerped_value = before + step * difference # 84.485

print(lerped_value) # 84.485
```

Below is an image (created using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)), with the dashed green lines representing linear interpolations between each of your points, the dashed red line representing index=1.85, and the red dot being the interpolated point (1.85, 84.485).
[image]

You could also write this as a function, of which I've included a few variants below, all of which implicitly assume you're importing `floor` and `ceil`.

```
def interpolate(data : list[list[float]], index : float) -> float:
    before, after = data[floor(index)][0], data[ceil(index)][0]
    step = index % 1
    difference = after - before
    lerped_value = before + step * difference
    return lerped_value
```

```
def interpolate(data : list[list[float]], index : float) -> float:
    before, after = data[floor(index)][0], data[ceil(index)][0]
    return before + (index % 1) * (after - before)
```

```
def interpolate(data : list[list[float]], index : float) -> float:
    return (before := data[floor(index)][0]) + (index % 1) * (data[ceil(index)][0] - before)
```

Which one you select is ultimately a matter of personal preference. I prefer the second, for the balance between brevity and clarity.

As a final note, you may also want to perform a linear regression on your points, as this may be less sensitive to errors in your data, and produce a smoother overall curve, if your data is linear.